# BitBloq: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typeerror

I am forked the BitBloq project: https://github.com/bq/bitbloq-frontend.git

Every single time I've run it on localhost I get the following error:

`

```
angular.js:12221 TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at X (angular-google-analytics.min.js:9)
    at angular-google-analytics.min.js:9
    at V (angular-google-analytics.min.js:9)
    at Object._trackPage (angular-google-analytics.min.js:9)
    at angular-google-analytics.min.js:9
    at Scope.$broadcast (angular.js:16038)
    at angular-route.js:619
    at processQueue (angular.js:14454)
    at angular.js:14470
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:15719)
```

`

I've no idea why is happening over and over.

I'll appreciate any idea about how to fix it and why it's happening.

Thank you so much.

Comment: can you explain more about how you run it?

Comment: I 've done the following steps:

1 . Clone the repo

2 . Execute this command to install all dependencies

npm install && bower install
3 . Then you need to add the enviroment files:

4 . Create a folder in app/res called config.

...

Comment: 5 . Create a file in app/res/config called config.json with this content

{
    "env": "local",
    "defaultLang": "es-ES",
    "supportedLanguages": [
        "es-ES",
        "en-GB",
        "nl-NL",
        "ru-RU",
        "it-IT",
        "eu-ES",
        "ca-ES",
        "fr-FR",
        "de-DE",
        "pt-PT",
        "gl",
        "zh-CN"
    ],

Comment: "saveTime": 2000,
    "serverUrl_": "http://localhost:8000/bitbloq/v1/",
    "gCloudUrl": "",
    "compilerUrl": "http://localhost:3000/",
    "bucket": "",
    "chromeAppId": "nlndpbeidnfnjpfkmlcakphlbilpokho",
    "web2boardLinkWindows": "https://github.com/bq/web2board/releases/download/Latest/windows_web2board_installer.exe",
    "web2boardLinkMac": "https://github.com/bq/web2board/releases/download/Latest/mac_web2board_installer.pkg",
    "web2boardLinkLinux": "https://github.com/bq/web2board/releases/download/Latest/linux_64_web2board_installer.zip",
    "web2boardLinkLinux32":

Comment: "https://github.com/bq/web2board/releases/download/Latest/linux_32_web2board_installer.zip",
    "version": "v3.3.6"
}

Comment: 6 . Create a file in app/res/config called facebook.json with the oauth info of Facebook, you need to fill the clientId field.

{
    "clientId": "yourID",
    "scope": [
        "public_profile",
        "email"
    ],
    "status": false,
    "xfbml": false,
    "display": "popup",
    "popupOptions": {
        "width": 500,
        "height": 500
    }
}

Comment: 7 . Create a file in app/res/config called google.json with the oauth info of Facebook, you need to fill the clientId and apikey fields

{
    "clientId": "Your clientId",
    "apikey": "Your Api Key",
    "scope": [
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/urlshortener",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file"
    ],

Comment: are you running any local server for your application?

Comment: "apis": [{
        "name": "plus",
        "version": "v1"
    }],
    "visibleActions": "http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity",
    "responseType": "token",
    "display": "popup",
    "popupOptions": {
        "width": 580,
        "height": 400
    }
}
8 . Execute the command

grunt serve

Comment: I am running the application at localhost:9000.

Comment: I'm using: sudo grunt serve

To run the application